# Struts2 : The requested list key could not be resolved Error

Tags: struts2

I'm sorry for posting so many questions, I think I need to read up more...

But first of all I was wondering if you guys can help me on this cos it's been bugging me for quite some time already and have been wondering why it's not working.

(This has nothing to do with the previous errors. Haven't got to solve that, and a new one is out :x)

I have a list that I want to populate to another, but in the process of doing so I got the error as titled :`The requested list key could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.`

I've looked around and tried the code but still it doesn't really seem to work. Here's my code:

JSP (and jquery):

```
<s:select id="feb" name="feb" headerKey="-1" list="febList" 
listKey="key" listValue="description" theme="simple" cssClass="formfields" />

$('select#feb').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "AnnotateSearchList?feb="+$(this).val()+"&dept="+$("#dept").val(),
                dataType :'json',
                type:'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success : function(data) {
                    alert('test');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error');                             
                }                                           
            })                                      
    });
```

The method:
   public String doGetSelectedList()
    {

```
    this.output = new StringBufferInputStream("");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);
    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (this.startDate == null || this.startDate.equals("")) {
        this.startDate = sdf.format(startCalendar.getTime()).toString();                
    }
    if (this.endDate == null || this.endDate.equals("")) {
        this.endDate = sdf.format(endCalendar.getTime()).toString();
    }

    System.out.println("Feb "+this.feb);
    System.out.println("Dept "+this.dept);  

    this.optionList =xxx.getList(this.feb, this.dept, this.startDate, this.endDate);

    ArrayList<SelectItemsData> optList = new ArrayList<SelectItemsData>();

    for(String list : optionList){          
        optList.add(new SelectItemsData(list, list));
    }

    System.out.println("Size of list: "+this.optionList.size());

    System.out.println(optList.size());
    String json = new Gson().toJson(optList);   
    logger.sendMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(), LogHandler.INFO, json);
    //System.out.println(json);
    try {
        response.setContentType("Application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        this.output = new StringBufferInputStream(json);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return SUCCESS;



}
```

//The Data holder for SelectItemsData:
    SelectItemsData(String key, String description);

struts/xml:

```
 <action name="AnnotateSearchList" class="mycompanyName.ajax.actions.ParetoChartCore"  method="doGetSelectedList">                                              
            <result type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/json</param>  
                <param name="inputName">output</param>     
            </result>               
            <result name="success">/ParetoChart.jsp</result>                                
        </action>
```

Am I going on wrong anywhere? My results are actually returning to the same page, so I thought that might be the possible cause of the error.
Thanks.

Comment: How you setting `febList` and go through the [select tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html) documentation to see how `listKey` and `listValue` works as your error saying its unable to find the key

Comment: hmm, the list is being fetched from the execute() method.

Comment: show code of the execute method

Comment: If your problem is with the rendering of that select tag, then all of this jquery and the action that backs the jquery ajax call seem to be irrelevant. Is it the select tag's febList that can't be found?

Comment: You have two results named "success" in the config you show above. "success" is the default name. I don't know if that's the *only* problem, but it's certainly a problem. You're also spending a lot of effort to create JSON when there's already a JSON plugin.

Comment: @Dave Newton : Can you explain on the 2 results? Basically I'm using strut's SUCCESS that renders to "success", so I highly doubt that it was this part that is giving me problem...

However you may be right on the JSON part... I'm using another JSON plugin but I could do a System.out.println and get the results of this JSON object.

The strange thing is, the Firebug does not show a JSON tab (if you use that for debugging, you'll know that there will be a JSON tab next to the "HTML" tab.)This JSON tab and its results is not showing, thus I was wondering if when it returns there becomes an error

Comment: @chad, I don't think there is a problem on the initial rendering, but it could be exausted after passing and returning some values.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "success" to "SUCCESS" in struts.xml and it worked.

Comment: That's because you had two results named "success" before. This is, however, *very* confusing, and I would strongly recommend you don't do it like this.